# Need of sbt-digest in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

What is the significance of using the sbt-digest plugin in play when it is mentioned in play's documentation that it can generate etags using the resource last modified date and the resource name, if sbt-digest is not being used.Are there benefits other than etags, for which one should use the sbt-digest plugin ?

Reference : - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#etag-support